# Change links at different areas on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make a website (all on one page). It has arrows on the top and bottom of the page. I need to use `position:fixed` so that the arrows can stay at the same place (I am using a Smooth Scroll plugin). I want the arrows to change link to the previous article (the ∧ link on the top of the page) and to the next article (the ∨ link on the bottom of the page) relative to the current article (the links go to the articles using `#articlename`)

The code I currently have is

```
<body>
<a href="#h"><div id="ntop">&and;</div></a>
<a href="#a"><div id="nbot">&or;</div></a>

<div id="page"><div id="h"></div><div id="section">
<h1>Welcome to Localhost.</h1>
<p>Localhost is a site. On your computer!</p>
</div>
<div id="a"></div><div id="section">
<h1>About Us.</h1>
<p>We are a group that make websites.</p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Add code quickly, or you'll get seriously flamed, my friend.

Comment: @RohanSood I have added the code of the Body, the other code is just links to the smooth scroll (which doesn't work), a Parallax Scrolling plugin (which doesn't work either), and my style.

Comment: so what is your question?

Comment: @Jean-Paul How to change the ∧ and ∨ links to change the location of the link to the appropriate pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First just a few things.. according to the HTML specification, you *cannot* put a `div` inside an `a`.. Try flipping them around, or set the `a` tag's CSS `display` to `block`. Also, you cannot use the same ID on multiple elements (for your `section` ID, I suggest using a class).

For each of your different "pages", use code like this:

```
<div class="page" id="page-PAGENUMBER">
    <!-- your page's code here -->
</div>
```

Where `PAGENUMBER` is a unique incrementing number, starting at 0 for the first page.

Change your two links to look like this:

```
<a id="ntop" href="javascript:void(0);" style="display:block;">&and;</a>
<a id="nbot" href="javascript:void(0);" style="display:block;">&or;</a>
```

Using these changes, you can update your current code to look like this:

```
<body>
<a id="ntop" href="javascript:void(0);" style="display:block;">&and;</a>
<a id="nbot" href="javascript:void(0);" style="display:block;">&or;</a>

<div class="page" id="page-0">
    <h1>Welcome to Localhost.</h1>
    <p>Localhost is a site. On your computer!</p>
</div>
<div class="page" id="page-1">
    <h1>About Us.</h1>
    <p>We are a group that make websites.</p>
</div>
</body>
```

And then add some Javascript code to your page like this:

```
<script>
    // Stores the current page
    var current_page = 0;

    // On previous page click
    $("#ntop").click(function() {
        current_page--; // Decrement current page
        document.location.hash = "page-" + current_page; // Update URL hash
    });

    // On next page click
    $("#nbot").click(function() {
        current_page++; // Increment current page
        document.location.hash = "page-" + current_page; // Update URL hash
    });
</script>
```

*This code assumes you are using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)*

Hope this helps!